# Nodejs & sequalize mysql query to the database happens only once

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following node code,i am trying to query the database based on a request,i use sequelize orm with mysql

```
  const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const axios = require("axios");
    const models = require("./models");

    const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

    app.post("/auth/change", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
      let phoneNumber = req.body.phone;
      let password = req.body.password;


      console.log("phone number", phoneNumber);

      models.users
        .findOne({
          where: {
            phone: phoneNumber
          }
        })
        .then(user => {
          console.log(user.name);
    }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      });
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

I use react on the front end, and when i send a request with data for example
{phone:777,password:123} it works, but if i do a second request with same or different data it fails.What am i missing here!!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not returning any data to the front side when it call the API , so the server will be waiting to return a response to the caller.

try to change your code to this :

```
models.users
    .findOne({
      where: {
        phone: phoneNumber
      }
    })
    .then(user => {
      res.status(200).send('ok')
}).catch(error => {
     res.status(400).send('not ok')
    });
```